# Mysl hangs when calling function inside select

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL. I have a query:

```
select distinct a.continent_code, a.country_code, a.city_code
from t_lst_ip4 a
where a.idncode = (select f_get_ip4_code(in_ip4_desc));
```

`select f_get_ip4_code(in_ip4_desc)` 
by itself is a function that always returns -1;

it looks like this:

```
delimiter $$
use `geoloc`$$
drop function if exists `test1`$$
use `geoloc`$$
create function `geoloc`.`test1`
(a int) returns int
begin
    return -1;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

When running this function separately, it works fine and fast.

When calling mentioned SELECT with just '-1' (that function always returns) it works fine.

I guess it has something to do with calling a function inside select?
separately everything works fine.

I guess function executes as many times as there are rows.

So if I have 3M rows, the function will execute 3M time.

I left only 3K entries in the table and now that select runs fast.

Is this how functions are originally executed inside SELECT?

Comment: Why you need a select/subquery? it's enough `where a.idncode = f_get_ip4_code(in_ip4_desc);`... And you do not need `BEGIN .. END` (and delimiter reassigning) in function creation code, simply ``create function `geoloc`.`test1`
(a int) returns int return -1;``

Comment: What u say is true, but I have another question. Should it act as it does in this situation? is this a normal behaviour?  If it is, then why?

Comment: Subquery wrap have too high overhead while comparing with direct function execution. Prepare, build plan, build record structure, search (within one value, of course, but nevertheless).

Comment: So this is how function execution inside select normally goes right?

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the keyword `DETERMINISTIC` to the `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Comment: Tried, no difference. Any other opinion?
I'm going to leave this at 5 Millisecond for now.